# Java: Convert floating point decimal number to the power of to integer

Tags: java, decimal, point

So I have the following number

```
3.454545E5
```

Notice the "E" letter which indicates to the power of

Is there a way to conver this number to

```
3454545
```

?

Comment: You mean you are parsing the string?

Comment: I don't get the question, are you just trying to drop the decimal and E5 from a string number? Or does that E represent scientific notation and in that case wouldn't the number be 345454

Comment: @j.con Yes I want to drop teh decimal and E5 from the number.

Answer (score 4):

```
double d = 3.454545E5;
int i = (int) d;
```

Output: 345454.

If you want exactly 3454545:

```
int i = (int) (d*10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use DecimalFormat to format the number any way you want.

If it is a string, first parse it as a double.

Answer (score 2):

```
double yourNumber = 3.454545E5;
String output = String.format("%d", yourNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
long l = (long) 3.454545E5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but looks like you're interested in extracting mantissa from the number and dropping the exponent

This should work for you:

```
double number = 3.454545E5;  
int exponent = (int)Math.log10(Math.abs(number));  // exponent = 5
double mantissa = number / Math.pow(10, exponent); // mantisa = 3.454545
```

To get your number you can multiply mantissa, in your particular example:

```
int result = (int)(mantissa * 1000000)
//result = 3454545
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this?

```
    double num = 3.454545E5;
    int num1 = (int)num;

    System.out.println(num1);
```

Here is the result  - 
    345454

Comment: so, whoever down voted, can they explain the reason?

Comment: if the reason is repeated answers, you should keep in the mind that all the answers were posted within 2-3 minutes, so person answering doesn't know if other answering the same solution.